# Enable/Disable a button on select of radio button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page in which there are 2 radio buttons and a next button. I have made next button disabled and it is enabled only when I select any radio button. But now when I go to another page and come back to this page the next button comes as disabled although the radio button is already selected. PFB the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#commandButton_1_0').attr('disabled', 'true');
     $('input:radio[name=a_SignatureOption]').click(function () {
         var checkval = $('input:radio[name=a_SignatureOption]:checked').val();
         if (checkval == '1' || checkval == '2') {
             $('#commandButton_1_0').removeAttr('disabled');
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio[name=a_SignatureOption]').click(function() {
        var checkval = $('input:radio[name=a_SignatureOption]:checked').val();
        $('#commandButton_1_0').prop('disabled', !(checkval == '1' || checkval == '2'));
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m6PVz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

On load of document you need to check whether radio button is clicked or not

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:radio[name=a_SignatureOption]').each(function() {
         checked(this);
  });

  $('input:radio[name=a_SignatureOption]').click(function() {
    checked(this);
  });

  function checked(obj){
    if($(obj).is(':checked')) {
        $('#commandButton_1_0').removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
        $('#commandButton_1_0').attr('disabled', 'true');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I took time to understand your problem,

This can be solved by **unchecking the radio while loading the page**.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:radio[name=a_SignatureOption]').prop('checked', false);
    $('#commandButton_1_0').attr('disabled', 'true');  
    $('input:radio[name=a_SignatureOption]').click(function () {
    var checkval = $('input:radio[name=a_SignatureOption]:checked').val();
    if (checkval == '1' || checkval == '2') {
        $('#commandButton_1_0').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
});
```

check out [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/m6PVz/4/), btw redirect to other site and  press back button to find the difference.

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

// Try this.............

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input:radio[name=a_SignatureOption]").removeAttr('checked'); 
$('#commandButton_1_0').attr("disabled","disabled");

 $('input:radio[name=a_SignatureOption]').click(function () {
    var checkval = $('input:radio[name=a_SignatureOption]:checked').val();   
     if (checkval == '1' || checkval == '2') {

         $('#commandButton_1_0').removeAttr("disabled","disabled");
     }
 });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

It is simple as your question is

```
<form name="urfrm">
<input type="radio" value="1" name="a_SignatureOption"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="a_SignatureOption"> No<br>
<input type="submit" id="butn" name="butn" value="next" disabled><br>
</form>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //This will check the status of radio button onload
    $('input[name=a_SignatureOption]:checked').each(function() {
        $("#butn").attr('disabled',false);
    });

    //This will check the status of radio button onclick
    $('input[name=a_SignatureOption]').click(function() {
        $("#butn").attr('disabled',false);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I can think of - albeit somewhat belatedly, is:

```
// selects all input elements, whose name is 'a_SignatureOption' and whose
// type is 'radio'
// binds a change event-handler, using 'on()':
$('input[name=a_SignatureOption][type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
    // sets the 'disabled' property of the button to 'true' if zero radio inputs
    // are checked, or to false if one is checked:
    $('#commandButton_1_0').prop('disabled', $('input[name=a_SignatureOption][type="radio"]:checked').length === 0);
// triggers the change event-handler on page load:
}).change();
```

References:

- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to check the buttons at the beginning.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#commandButton_1_0').attr('disabled', 'true');
    if( $('input[name=a_SignatureOption]:checked' ).size() > 0 ) {
       $('#commandButton_1_0').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    $('input[name=a_SignatureOption]').click(function () {
        if( $('input:radio[name=a_SignatureOption]:checked' ).size() > 0 ) {
            $('#commandButton_1_0').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

By the way, I always suggest to add classes to form elements and work with those, instead of using [name="..."]. It's quicker and simplier and you can change input names (if necessary) without touching js

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#commandButton_1_0').attr('disabled', 'true');

        $('input:radio[name=a_SignatureOption]').click(function () {
            var checkval = $('input:radio[name=a_SignatureOption]:checked').val();
            alert(checkval)
            if (checkval == '1' || checkval == '2') {
                $('#commandButton_1_0').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
            else {
                $('#commandButton_1_0').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="radio" name="a_SignatureOption" value="1" /> value1
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="a_SignatureOption" value="2"/> value2
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="a_SignatureOption" value="3" checked="checked"/> value3
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="commandButton_1_0" value="Next"/>
</body>
</html>
```